# Is this the correct way to run scheduled async/await methods using System.Threading.Timer?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, timer, async-await

I am currently working on a project where I would like to perform some periodic updates in the background and I would like to use async/await for that purpose using a System.Threading.Timer. I have not been able to find any articles on this particular subject.

The following snippet works. I am just unsure about using a async method returning void when that should only be used for event handlers like button clicks. Is there anything that 'breaches' with best practice in the code below?

```
public class ScheduledCache
{
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private Request _request = new Request();
    private Timer _timer;

    public void Start()
    {
        _cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _timer = new Timer(UpdateAsync, null, 2000, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _cancelSource.Cancel();
    }

    public async void UpdateAsync(object state)
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(UpdateSomethingAsync(_cancelSource.Token), UpdateSomethingElseAsync(_cancelSource.Token));
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            // Handle cancellation
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // Handle exception
        }
        finally
        {
            if (_cancelSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                _timer = new Timer(UpdateAsync, null, 2000, Timeout.Infinite);
            else
                _timer = new Timer(UpdateAsync, null, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
        }
    }

    private async Task UpdateSomethingAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await Task.Run(new Action(_request.UpdateSomething));
    }

    private async Task UpdateSomethingElseAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await Task.Run(new Action(_request.UpdateSomethingElse));
    }
}

public class Request
{
    public void UpdateSomething()
    {
        // Do some updates here
    }

    public void UpdateSomethingElse()
    {
        // Do some other updates here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am just unsure about using a async method returning void when that should only be used for event handlers like button clicks

Well, you're registering an event handler to the `Timer.Elapsed` event, so using it in such a manner is ok.

Generally, I'd do a couple of things differently. First, using the [*async over sync anti-pattern*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx), which I would avoid. Move `Task.Run` to the highest place possible in the callstack. Then, if you're only invoking a one-liner async method, simply return it instead of awaiting on it, allowing you to save the async state-machine generation.

Another thing you may consider is instead of using a `Timer` you can loop and use `Task.Delay`, which internally uses a timer but exposes a `Task` to the caller.

It can roughly look like this:

```
public async Task StartAsync()
{
    _cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    await UpdateAsync(_cancelSource.Token);
}

public async Task UpdateAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
         var updateSomething = Task.Run(() => _request.UpdateSomething()));
         var updateSomethingElse = Task.Run(() => _request.UpdateSomethingElse());

        await Task.WhenAll(updateSomething, updateSomethingElse);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        // Handle cancellation
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        // Handle exception
    }
    finally
    {
        if (_cancelSource.IsCancellationRequested)
            await Task.Delay(2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Good input. Yeah, I was unsure how the method would be invoked. I totally agree on moving the Task.Run as high up as possible. Cleaner code. I do see the anti-pattern now. Not always obvious for newcomers to async/await.